# Prevent caching when using wp_enqueue_script?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, cache

I am using this to include a custom js file, but i notice if i update the custom-js.js file it doesn't automaticly is the one used? So how do i prevent this js file to be cached?

```
function my_custom_js() {
    if (is_page(422) || is_page(97) || is_page(3970)) {
        wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-js'
                . '.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', TRUE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bump the version number - `1.0.0` to something like `1.0.1`

Comment: oh didn't realise it as i couldn't see the version number in the generated html source code, TX